# How do Catholics explain the stance of Pope Paul VI on contraception?

Tags: catholicism, ethics, contraception

Pope Paul VI, in his *Humanae Vitae* (1968)said that, "**It is always intrinsically wrong to use contraception to prevent new human beings from coming into existence."** [(source)](http://www.catholic.com/tracts/birth-control)

The words of the Pope are explicit. He said that contraception (= preventing new human beings from coming into existence)was always intrinsically wrong. In other words, every form of contraception must have always been intrinsically wrong per the Pope's very own words.

How do Catholics explain the stance of Pope Paul VI on contraception?

NOTE

This is not about the natural or artificial kinds of contraception. This question focuses on the encyclical of the Pope entitled "Human Life" (1968).

Comment: @RadzMatthewCoBrown We might be able to save this question by focusing on the how the Church defines contraception. Contraception for the Church means *impeding the fecundity of an otherwise fertile sexual act*, not *preventing new human beings from coming into existence.* What if we changed the question to something like "How does the Catholic Church define contraception"?

Comment: @AthanasiusOfAlex That would be a completely different question.  Why encourage to the OP to change this one into a different question instead of simply asking a new question  (esp. considering someone answered this one already)?

Comment: @AthanasiusOfAlex, No. No one will change my question. My question rests on a solid basis. I based it on the Pope's definition of contraception.

Comment: Except I don't think it *is* (that) Pope's definition of contraception, it's his description of what contraception could be *used for*. I stand by my belief that this is a duplicate.

Comment: Natural Family Planning (NFP) is not contra-ceptive but it's non-conceptive because it uses abstinence during fertile times instead of blocking fertility.

Comment: @MattGutting, I edited my question. You know what? Even if your interpretation is correct, the inclusion of natural *contraception* would be inevitable. The reason is that it is still prevents new human beings into coming into existence.

Comment: The [official text](http://w2.vatican.va/content/paul-vi/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-vi_enc_25071968_humanae-vitae.html) of *Humanae Vitae* doesn't include the quoted sentence.

Comment: @ThaddeusB OK, better to ask a new question. As it stands, I agree with Matt Gutting and the others that it is a duplicate. (My reason for suggesting the change is that there seems to be a slight misunderstanding in the wording of the question as to what the Catholic Church understands contraception to mean.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach The source of my quotation says their info's are "free from errors."

Comment: @RadzMatthewCoBrown Free from doctrinal and moral errors. The text at the page is not the text of *Humanae vitae* (and, to be fair, doesn't represent itself as such: but neither should anyone else represent it as the text).

Answer (score 1):

Natural contraception leaves open the chance that life may begin due to some unforeseen occurrence like out of monthly cycle an egg was released that could be at the right place at the right time. Artificial contraception involves the woman or man taking direct action to prevent the occurrence of pregnancy at which point sexual union  becomes a selfish act.
The Church also says that artificial contraception is morally wrong, because each and every sex act can occur only between husband and wife and must be directed toward two ends: love and life, that is, the intimate unity between the man and woman (love) and possibly procreating another human being (life). Conception and pregnancy don’t have to occur each time, but no man-made barriers should prevent what God may intend to happen.

Comment: This is a decent answer (though without references) but I'm pretty sure the question is a duplicate.